# Showing appointment by LocalID does not work, but RoamingID works - why?

Tags: calendar, uwp, windows-10-universal

From my app I want to show [`Appointment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297221) details to the user using the built-in calendar of Windows. So I call `AppointmentManager.ShowAppointmentDetailsAsync(appointment.LocalId)` - which does open the calendar app, but does **not** open the appointment details but rather jumps to the current date and shows the calendar.

But when calling `AppointmentManager.ShowAppointmentDetailsAsync(appointment.RoamingId)` (**RoamingId** instead of **LocalId**) it works as intended - the appointment is being opened in edit mode in the calendar app.

Now the documentation for [`AppointmentManager.ShowAppointmentDetailsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn624716.aspx) states about its ID parameter:

> **appointmentId**
>
> Type: String [JavaScript] | System.String [.NET] |
>   Platform::String [C++] The **LocalId** of the appointment to be displayed.

What is this? Wrong documentation? A bug? Shouldn't this work using the local appointment ID?

(SDK Version 10.0.14393.0, Win 10 Anniversary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. This seems to be a documentation issue. The `appointmentId` parameter used in [AppointmentManager.ShowAppointmentDetailsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showappointmentdetailsasync.aspx) method should be the same as what used in [ShowReplaceAppointmentAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showreplaceappointmentasync.aspx) or [ShowRemoveAppointmentAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showreplaceappointmentasync.aspx) method. In these two methods, `appointmentId` is typically obtained from the async return value of a previous [ShowAddAppointmentAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showaddappointmentasync) or [ShowReplaceAppointmentAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.showreplaceappointmentasync.aspx) call, which actually is the [Appointment.RoamingId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointment.roamingid).

We will report this issue internally. You can also use the Feedback at the bottom of every Windows Dev Center page to send your feedback. Your feedback has made Windows better!

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I wasn't sure if the docs are wrong. All of your linked MSDN pages just talk about identifiers but never mention if this is the Roaming or Local one.